# Random Forest: Missing Values

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, random-forest

One of the features in my random forest model has missing values. There are 5 reasons for the data is missing and I know the reason for all the missing values. My question is how can I feed this information into the model? I can create a categorical variable (or encoded dummies) for the reason of the data being missing but how can I make sure that random forest gets information from this categorical variable when there is a missing value in my main variable?

Comment: Just impute the missing values for that variable as "Empty" or "Unknown"?

Comment: The variable is continuous so I'm not sure if that would be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another variable will not help you much, because 1) Random For
rest assumes independence of the variables, so you will not be able to entangle two variables and 2) it does not guarantee that it will use it all.

If you want to use Random Forest, you will have to impute the missing values one way or another.

The most simple approach is if your variable is in some range, set the missing values to an out of range values encoding the reasons. That is if  your variable lays in range [-1..1], set the missing value (say) to -101 if the reason is reason #1, -102 for the reason #2, etc. The idea is to allow the algorithm find a distinct borders between different values.

Second [method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyxTdL_4Q-Q) called MissForest is a bit more computationally complex. As you don't know the value, information about why you miss it does not contribute much. Still, you can find the best value to set instead of the missing one iteratively.

Comment: Setting the missing value (say) to -101 if the reason is reason #1, -102 for the reason #2, etc would mean ranking the reasons which I believe is not very correct as they are not ordinal. But thank you!

Comment: You are correct, first method is very naive. Use second one for better results. `MissForest` does not lay any assumptions and even in a few iterations provide good results.